# IMAGE_FSTYPES= "img" on Yocto Project

Tags: image, filesystems, yocto

I am using yocto to build a raspberry pi image, I am tring to get a .img file as an output of the build but I am geting this error:

```
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-core/images/meta-networking-image.bb: No IMAGE_CMD defined for IMAGE_FSTYPES entry 'img' - possibly invalid type name or missing support class
ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /home/ubuntu/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-core/images/meta-networking-image.bb
```

the following is the meta-networking-image.bb:

```
require  meta-networking-image-base.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL += "packagegroup-meta-networking"
```

the following is the meta-networking-image-base.bb:

```
SUMMARY = "meta-networking build test image"

IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-core-boot"

LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit core-image.
```

does anyone has a clue how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Yocto has a [defined](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-IMAGE_TYPES) list for supported image file types.

Each type has an entry in IMAGE_CMD variable like: IMAGE_CMD_jffs2 defining the command to generate a jffs2 image.

So, "img" type is not defined in the supported list,to add new type as described [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_CMD):

> Specifies the command to create the image file for a specific image
> type, which corresponds to the value set set in IMAGE_FSTYPES, (e.g.
> ext3, btrfs, and so forth). When setting this variable, you should use
> an override for the associated type. Here is an example:
>
> ```
>  IMAGE_CMD_jffs2 = "mkfs.jffs2 --root=${IMAGE_ROOTFS} \
>     --faketime --output=${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${IMAGE_NAME}.rootfs.jffs2 \
>     ${EXTRA_IMAGECMD}"
> ```
>
> You typically do not need to set this variable unless you are adding
> support for a new image type. For more examples
> on how to set this variable, see the image_types class file, which is
> meta/classes/image_types.bbclass.

So, to add your new custom image:

- create new image class by copying image_types.bbclass as a reference and named to image_img.bbclass for example
- customized to add IMAGE_CMD_img entry with "img" image generation command

After that, do not forget to add your new image_img.bbclass class to IMAGE_CLASSES variable and add "img" to IMAGE_FSTYPES variable.

I didn't find anything related to "img" type actually.